# How to use sourcemaps with node.js workder_threads using eval option?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am spinning up my express application written in TypeScript using the [`Worker`](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html#class-worker) provided by core `workder_threads` module.

I use esbuild to compile and bundle the TS code into a single file with sourcemaps `'inline'` as:

```js
const ctx = await esbuild.context({
  format: 'cjs',
  sourcemap:'inline',
  entryPoints: ['./server/main.ts'],
  bundle: true,
  platform: 'node',
  outfile: './dist/server/main.js',
  logLevel: 'silent',
  color: true,
  
  // Keep the compiled output in-memory and don't write to disk.
  write: false
});
```

I execute this compiled code as:

```js
// Build the code using 
const result = await ctx.rebuild();
const toExecute = result.outputFiles.find((x) => x.path.endsWith('main.js'));

// The toExecute.text content the compiled code.
// The eval: true enable to pass code as a string
// instead of filename to the Worker instance.
const serverWorker = new worker.Worker(toExecute.text, {
  eval: true,
});
```

Everything runs file except for the **sourcemaps**. I am able to get sourcemaps working if I don't use `eval`, and instead use the actual compiled file written to the disk.

So, how do I achieve this with `eval`?